# How can I prevent Autofac from injecting null when accidentally used an invalid key?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, nullreferenceexception

I've run into an issue recently where for a [Keyed Service](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) I accidentally used an invalid key. I was using enums and it turned out that a similar one was defined in a 3rd party library. As a result of mixing them up Autofac injected a `null` dependency and we had to debug it for a while until we found the reason.

My question is whether there is a mechanism that would prevent Autofac from injecting/resolving a `null` service if a key does not exist? I was thinking of Autofac throwing an exception that a dependency could not be resolved as it does in many other cases.

I've created a demo that demonstrates this issue:

```
void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder
        .RegisterType<Class1>()
        .Keyed<IInterface>(Key.First);

    builder
        .RegisterType<Class2>()
        .Keyed<IInterface>(Key.Second);

    builder
        .RegisterType<Class>()
        .WithAttributeFiltering();

    var container = builder.Build();
    var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();

    scope.Resolve<Class>().Dump();;
}

interface IInterface { }

class Class1 : IInterface { }
class Class2 : IInterface { }

class Class
{
    public Class([KeyFilter(DifferentKey.First)] IInterface i)
    {
        i.Dump(); // null because the key is wrong
    }
}

enum Key
{
    First,
    Second
}

enum DifferentKey
{
    First,
    Second
}
```

Comment: Create unit tests to check if your classes and dependencies are resolved properly.

Comment: @RuiJarimba I'd rather not to because I didn't have to do it until now because in all other cases Autofac is complaining about missing dependencies... however, not this time. I prefer to rely on its mechanism without unit-testing dependency-injection.

Comment: I think I would rather have it that way you are already doing it. I would want it to crash. And crash early. If you know it's NRE on an injected resource, injection fails. If injection fails, then something is messed up with the resolution, so check it. Pretty straight forward ... imho. I kinda disagree with the unit test, though because I would expect a Mock to be injected. Or would you explicitly write a separate test to test injection @RuiJarimba ?

Comment: @Fildor this is a typical example on how things can go wrong with a IoC container. I'm not sure what exactly do you mean by `I would want it to crash. And crash early` - if you mean waiting for things to crash in runtime, it might be already too late. I'd rather have unit tests for the dependencies that would run as part of a CI build, I blogged about that recently: [Unit Testing your IoC Container](https://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2018/10/01/unit-testing-your-ioc-container/). That blog post is about Unity but the idea/concept is the same :-)

Comment: @RuiJarimba Awesome!! Thanks for the link! I was looking for exactly something like that a couple of months ago.

Comment: @RuiJarimba IoC unit-testing is ridiculous as the whole idea of DI is to be able to quickly change or add dependencies. Adding unit-tests to it would mean to constantly having to maintain them. This is way too much work. Besides this case could not be tested with a unit-test as resolving it from a container in another place where you use the correct key would work and yet the actual user of that service would get a `null` anyway.

Comment: @t3chb0t no it's not ridiculous, I've seen many runtime exceptions in the past when an IoC container was trying to resolve a particular dependency. IMO it makes sense to run unit tests to check if the dependencies can be resolved or not - or do you prefer to wait for a runtime error in production?

Comment: `Adding unit-tests to it would mean to constantly having to maintain them` - if you write tests you do need to maintain them, it makes perfect sense - it doesn't matter if we're talking about IoC Containers or not. Some containers do make your life easier, such as unity. It's quite easy to iterate the dependencies and try to resolve them, as I have shown in my blog post that I mentioned above

Comment: @RuiJarimba there are no such runtime production errors as IoC exceptions can be successfuly cought either during development or on the staging system. Unit-testing makes sense for the most simple and basic components. Anything higher than that requires integration tests and anything other than real integrations tests is pretty unreliable. You wouldn't disover this particular issue in a unit-test because it occurs only when running in real world scenario. That's why integration-tests are the most valueable ones.

Comment: But in some cases maybe it would make more sense to write an integration or smoke test

Comment: @RuiJarimba well, anyway... this is kind of off-topic ;-] lets stick to Autofac and it not complaining about the `null` where it does for anything else.

Comment: Ok, at least we agree that it makes sense to create some tests :-)

Comment: @RuiJarimba sure, I have plenty of them but only where they have some signifficant value ;-) As far as Autofac is concered I was very surprised when it injected a nothing. Has it told me that the key does not exist, I would have instantly found the bug and I would be happy if I could _convince_ it to do so also for keys ;-]

Comment: I was wondering if Autofac has something such as [StructureMap's AssertConfigurationIsValid](http://structuremap.github.io/diagnostics/validating-container-configuration/)?

Comment: @RuiJarimba Oh, then I have to dig deeper. This would be awsome if there was something like this. The whole discussion about unit-testing would then be obsolete. The container could test itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IIndex` to inject dependencies if you really need an error in case of missing dependency.

```
class Class
{

        public Class(IIndex<DataType, ITestItem> list)
        {
            //Throws error if you try to get the instance for unregistered key
            var test = list[DataType.Type2];

        }
}
```